# pH calculations, speeding up code involving Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to calculate pH values of solutions containing water and acetic acid.
The relevant equations have been defined and I now want to find a solution using Mathematica.

For a specific acid concentration (0.0001) I can do the following.

```
Solve[(concentrations && equilibrium && requirements) /. {c2 -> 0.0001}]
```

But I would prefer to solve the system of equations once and then insert the acid concentration. But the following code does not work

```
Solve[(concentrations && equilibrium && requirements)] /. {c2 -> 0.0001}
```

Which throws the following error

```
Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact 
coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding 
exact system and numericizing the result. >>"
```

My working code so far is shown here

```
concentrations = cHp == c1 + c3 && cOHm == c1 && cCH3COOm == c3 && cCH3COOH == c2 - c3;
equilibrium = 10^-14 == cHp cOHm && 1.1614 10^-5 == cCH3COOm cHp/cCH3COOH;
requirements = cHp > 0 && cOHm > 0 && cCH3COOH > 0 && cCH3COOm > 0;
Plot[-Log[10, cHp] /. 
  Solve[(concentrations && equilibrium && requirements) /. {c2 -> 
      x}], {x, 0, 0.00010}, PlotRange -> {2, 9}]
```

Comment: I presume you know the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation?

Comment: In that form I know it. But this example is meant as an example of what can be achieved with Mathematica. And as I can do the calculations by hand I expect that Mathematica can also do it if I ask it the right way.

Comment: You're using molars, I gather?

Comment: By the way, where'd you get your $K_a$ value for acetic acid? I get $\approx 1.74\times 10^{-5}$. Anyway, I can't see how you can do better than `With[{c = 0.1}, -Log10[x] /. First@Solve[10^-4.76 == x^2/(c - x) && x > 0, x]]`...

Comment: Can get something reasonable by plugging in a positive value for cHp, e.g. `N@NSolve[(concentrations && equilibrium) /. {c2 -> x, cHp -> 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]`

Comment: @Daniel, for this particular case, `2` would be a rather unrealistic value of the concentration `cHp` (in chemistry terms, acetic acid is a weak acid); typical values in applications are usually less than `1` in magnitude (and positive, of course).

Comment: Your `Solve` doesn't specify the variables you want to solve for...

Comment: To get rid of the warning message you could either replace the numeric values with symbolic constants or with rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me, removing the `requirements` from `Solve` and filtering the solutions afterwards.

```
soln = Solve[concentrations && equilibrium, {cHp, cCH3COOm, cCH3COOH, c1, c3, cOHm}];
```

This gives three solutions, so select the one for which the `requirements` are satisfied at some reasonable value of `c2`.

```
soln = Select[soln, requirements /. Chop[# /. c2 -> 10^-5] &];
```

The solution can now be plotted:

```
Plot[-Log[10, cHp /. soln], {c2, 0, 0.00010}, PlotRange -> {2, 9}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `Solve` makes use of `$Assumptions` which means that `Assuming` doesn't have any influence on `Solve`.

Comment: @Heike, thanks. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Still, as I already mentioned, doing some of the work for `Solve[]` helps a lot: `Plot[-Log10[x] /. First@Solve[10^-4.76 == x^2/(c - x) && x > 0, x], {c, 0, 10^-4}, PlotRange -> {2, 9}]`.